# Use JSP in grails application

Tags: grails, grails3

I migrate java web application into grails. I have some legacy JSP views located in /src/main/webapp folder. Is there a way to use them in my grails controllers without moving them into grails-app folder.

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. The .gsp syntax is far more pleasant anyway. Are you unable to convert them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using groovyPagesTemplateEngine
http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2010/05/grails-goodness-use-gsp-template-engine.html